# Change audio output socket on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound, output

My output audio socket is broken. In Windows I can change sockets input and output with "Realtek". Is there a way to change audio sockets on Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: Open settings and go to sound then choose the output there

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PulseAudio, you should be able to do it by running `pavucontrol`. Go to output devices and see if you can select another output there.

Comment: how can i install Pulseaudio on 15.04??

Comment: You don't need to install pulseaudio, it's part of the system. You need to install pavucontrol.